# VB.NET: how to transfer values from access into variables

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, time

I want to retrieve value Of TIMEIN and TIMEOUT from Access and store it into variables for later use. The piece of code which I am trying is not working. Here is the code:

```
Public timein As DateTime
Public timeout As DateTime 
Dim selectquery As String

    selectquery = "SELECT * FROM emp_timing " & "WHERE emp_code = @p1 AND day = @p2"


    Using con = New OleDbConnection(dbProvider & dbSource)
        Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, con)

            timein = cmd.Parameters.Item("emp_timein")
            timeout = cmd.Parameters.Item("emp_timeout")

            con.Open()

            'cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = System.DateTime.Now
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", OleDbType.Date).Value = New DateTime(Now.Year, Now.Month, Now.Day)

            Try

                Dim rowsSelect = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
                If rowsSelect > 0 Then
                    MsgBox("Data added to variables")

                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)

            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
```

Comment: so what is the error?  is it something to do with data type conversion?  It helps if we know the problem to be solved

Comment: This is the error: Value of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter' cannot be converted to 'Date'.

Comment: First you need to move that ERROR HERE code to **after** you execute the query; then change it to `ExecuteReader` and then read the values from the returned data reader

Comment: I moved that code before **after**  `Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, con)`. but the error is same and when I changed to ExecuteReader it shows the error "Operator '>' is not defined for types 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader' and 'Integer'".

Comment: You did more than move code lines.  The code posted has no `>`, so [Edit] your post with the new code

Comment: now it does not shows that operator error because I have used `Dim rowsSelect = cmd.ExecuteScalar()`.

Comment: but this error is still there: Value of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter' cannot be converted to 'Date'.

Comment: a) executescalar is **wrong** if you want more than one value from the db. Use `Dim dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()`.  b) THAT LINE is what reads from the DB, so assign your time vars AFTER you read from it: `timein = COnvert.ToDateTime(dr("emp_timein"))`

Comment: you mean to say that I should add `timein = COnvert.ToDateTime(dr("emp_timein"))` **after** `Dim rowsSelect = cmd.ExecuteReader()`?

Answer (score 0):

Replace ExecuteNonQuery with ExecuteReader or ExecuteScaler depending on your needs. To retrieve result set from database against select query, you'll be using ExecuteReader

See [MSDN Documentstion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/979byfca(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Comment: It shows the error: 'ExecuteQuery' is not a member of 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand'.

Comment: `Dim dr=cmd.ExecuteReader()`

Comment: @Plutonix yes. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/979byfca(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Comment: Using scalar it does not shows any error but on reader it shows.

Comment: See documentation and adjust your code accordingly. ExecuteReader is not a drop in replacement for ExecuteNonQuery. Both serve different purpose.